# Сделать из DataFrame словарь без индексов

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

Пытаюсь сначала записывать данные в .сsv файл, затем считывать их оттуда. Но при считывании возникает такая проблема: я записываю данные в словарь, но вместе с моими данными в словаре появляется индекс строки, который я бы хотел убрать.

Можно ли сделать это на Pandas?

Я записываю данные так:

```py
params_data = pd.DataFrame(params, index=['value'])
params_data.to_csv(params_filename, sep=',')
```

Вот так выглядят данные после записи их в DataFrame:

```py
          metric  n_neighbors  p  weights
value  minkowski            8  6  uniform
```

Но когда я считываю их этим методом:

```py
params = params_data.to_dict(orient='records')
```

Словарь выглядит вот так:

```py
[{'Unnamed: 0': 'value', 'metric': 'minkowski', 'n_neighbors': 8, 'p': 6, 'weights': 'uniform'}]
```

Можно ли как-то избавить от ключа "Unnamed" и его значения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь параметром `index=False`:

```
params_data.to_csv(..., index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Кроме предложенного решения нашел вот такое:

```py
params = params_data.iloc[0, 1:].to_dict()
```

Что работает, потому что в моем csv файле только одна строка, которая мне и нужна